# Can't set the power save on disks

Tags: windows-xp

My Windows XP "does" something non stop on my hard drive - about every minute, a short blink  (~0.2 sec.) of the disk activity diode, causing the power save options never to work.

This really sucks, I have disabled most of the services (like indexing, logging, page file, system restore stuff, but it still "performs" something very important)

Comment: Did you check your processes with Process Explorer? Maybe it can help you to figure out what's going on inside. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: Yes, use Process Explorer to track disk activity. It wouldn't surprise me if this was "normal".

Answer (score 3):

It could be the search indexer running, that would be my first guess. Here is a lifehacker post on how to disabled the indexer. Searching will still work even with this disabled, it just may take a bit longer.
[Disable XP Search Indexer](http://lifehacker.com/031440/turn-off-indexing-and-speed-up-windows-xp)